# Comunication betwen two *.php

Tags: php, html

I have login.php and register.php. In header.php i can see loged user. But i can not find the way how to logout.

Next is server.php

```
                    If (isset($_GET['Logout'])){
                     session_destroy();
                     unset($_SESSION['username']);
                     header("Location:homepage.php");
                     }
```

And next header.php where I have

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
           <?php include('server.php'); ?>

           <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
             <p> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p> 
             <a href="homepage.php?logout='1'">Logout</a>
           <?php endif ?>
           <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
             <p><?php echo "You are not loged" ?></p> 
           <?php endif ?>
```

And i am looking to find the way to get "You are not loged".
And no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: I dont see a `session_start()` anywhere in any of the code you show us????

Comment: There is a Uppercase char in $_GET['Logout'].

Comment: Thank you, it works i did correct the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing lowercase 'logout' but checking for sentence case 'Logout' in $_GET['Logout']

```
If (isset($_GET['logout'])){
   session_destroy();
   unset($_SESSION['username']);
   header("Location:homepage.php");
}
```

Also you will need session_start() in your php files as @RiggsFolly suggested.

Comment: I have session_start(). Thank you. I did correct the mistake and now is ok. Also another think. Is there a way to set an js variable to null in server.php code?

Comment: Not really but you can print null in your html using php's echo. You cannot do it in js file unless you use php to generate js file dynamically which is not good for performance because it will not be cached etc. So in your html, within the script tag you can say... var someVariable = <%= $NullOrWhatEverValue %>;